# Reading converted HEX data from SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not sure I am approaching this project correctly. I have a SQL Server database that contains annotation data for images. The annotation data is stored as a blob data type in the database.

First I tried using a `SELECT` statement to convert the blob to text:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max), CONVERT(varbinary(max), blob_column))    
FROM table
```

Then I used an online tool to convert it from HEX to ASCII. I was able to get more data from it. However, most of the converted text is junk. Below is a screenshot viewed in Notepad++.

[image]

Is it possible to convert that junk data into something useful? Is there another approach I should try?

Binary Code

```
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
```

Comment: If the annotation data was just text in the first place I would expect it to be stored as `varchar` or `nvarchar`, so the fact that it's stored as binary seems to suggest it's some specific binary format, possibly native to an application, and needs to be decoded via the appropriate decoder, no?

Comment: thats what i was afraid of.. i thought i would give it try

Comment: blobs usually don't need converting, simpy save the binary data as file or memorystream and used it  like any other image

Comment: Yes, good point... if the blob is not *just* the metdata, but rather the image as a whole, *including* the metadata, in some known image format, just write it out with the appropriate extension, and open it with the appropriate application. I should be clear that my comment is based on the premise that the blob contains metadata only.

Comment: There is no `blob` data type. There is `varbinary(max)` and there is `image`. Showing the first few actual hex bytes might give us a clue as to what format it's in (paste as text, no images please)

Comment: i finally have time to go back to this project. I attached my binary data that stores the annotation data..